# Syntax error for function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, syntax, while-loop, cursor, return

I am having trouble with the syntax of postgresql, mainly with return, while loop and cursor. If I don't want to return anything what should I write? What should be my while loop condition to go through the cursor?

```
CREATE FUNCTION price(category integer, reduce real, minimum integer)
RETURNS void;

DECLARE name VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE total integer;
DECLARE number integer;
BEGIN 

DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT people, quantity FROM store WHERE categories = category;

OPEN C1;

FETCH C1 INTO name, number; 

total = SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM store WHERE categories = category;

WHILE (condition) LOOP  
    IF(total > minimum)
        THEN UPDATE store SET (price = price - reduce) WHERE categories = category;
    END IF;
    FETCH C1 INTO name, number; 
END LOOP;

CLOSE C1; 
END;
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: 1) Just `return;` without parameters; 2) Use `FOUND` variable: [example](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-cursor/#crayon-56ea6d043addd111161561)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is overly complex and it has a few syntax errors on the opening and closing lines.

```
CREATE FUNCTION price(category integer, reduce real, minimum integer) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  total integer;
BEGIN 
  SELECT SUM(quantity) INTO total FROM store WHERE categories = category;
  IF total > minimum THEN
    UPDATE store SET price = price - reduce WHERE categories = category;
  END IF;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT VOLATILE;
```

You really do not want to use a cursor here, a single `UPDATE` statement is much more efficient.

Comment: I know its complex but I have to use a cursor and the while loop

Comment: Not with the example you show. Is this maybe some course work that you are in?